# OWD Private not working

Tags: owd

I've restricted access for Account and Order records in the system. Only owners should be able to access the data.

When I login as some user A(sys admin/ non sys admin), The account and order list view show me records owned by other user B also. Following are the steps implemented,

1. OWD of Account is set to private.
2. OWD on order is controlled by parent.
3. User A and B are at same level roles and report to CEO.
4. Modify All/View All is not enabled on users A and B profiles.

Please let me know if I'm missing something.

Comment: Do the profiles have View All Data or Modify All Data (not the same thing as View/Modify All at the object level)? Do you have any Sharing Rules in place? Are the users on the Account Team, if any? If you click the Sharing button for an affected Account, what do you see?

Comment: I don't have any sharing rules on account or view all/modify all access(on object as well as any sharing). When I go to sharing button on account, I only see the user who should have access but I'm logged in as the other user

Answer (score 1):

Best way to debug this is to go to the account that's visible by user B and click the "Sharing" button (available on Classic interface). The sharing screen will provide a table of all users with access to this record, and the reason for their access.

Comment: I don't have any sharing rules on account or view all/modify all access(on object as well as any sharing). When I go to sharing button on account, I only see the user who should have access but I'm logged in as the other user

Comment: Try checking the sharing screen while logged in as yourself - sys admin.